# Automatically resize tabpage on tab click (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, resize, tabpage

I would like my tabpage (and dialog) to resize when the tab is clicked.

For example:

- `Tab1` is `300x200`
- `Tab2` is `400x400`

The dialog opens in `Tab1` in `300x200`. When you click `Tab2`, the dialog and tabpage resizes to `400x400`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Dock() property of the TabControl to Fill, then handle the SelectedIndexChanged() event:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case TabControl1.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            Me.Size = New Size(300, 200)
        Case 1
            Me.Size = New Size(400, 400)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out as soon as I am able.